# How can I drop and recreate a database with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following code:

```
public class DataInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DataContext>
// public class DataInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DataContext>
// public class DataInitializer : MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DataContext, >
{
    public DataInitializer()
    {
        // System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Set Initializer\n");
        Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(null);

        try
        {
```

This does not seem to be dropping my database and recreating. Can someone give
me advice as to why it does not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing initializer by setting it to `null`. Make following initializer (suppose `DataContext` is your context class, inherited from `DbContext`):

```
public class DataInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DataContext>
{
    // optionally override Seed method
}
```

And at the start of application (before first creation of your context) call

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DataInitializer());
```

Consider also to use `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` initializer.